# How to setup ROS for multi-robot domains (roscores, namespaces for nodes, tf frames)

Tags: ros, best-practices, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please help in writing up a ROS best practice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11839/how-to-setup-ros-for-multi-robot-domains-(roscores,-namespaces-for-nodes,-tf-frames)/) by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8372 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For simulation you have a very complete answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/?answer=41434#post-id-41434) about how to manage node namespaces and tf issues.

Working with real robots makes it harder.
I suggest using a roscore in each robot, so that all data is private to each robot.
In order to share certain topics, you can use packages such as [ros-rt-wmp](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ros-rt-wmp?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=linkto%3A%22ros-rt-wmp%22), which provides a wireless communication protocol that propagate selective topics to other roscores.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Urcola](https://answers.ros.org/users/545/pablo-urcola/) with karma: 188 on 2012-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0